# can i submit approval to email id instead of User

Tags: approval-process

I want to use custom Approval process, Is it possible to directly assign an email id as an approver instead of assigning it to a user??

Comment: I don't think salesforce supports that feature. However, you can approve records using emails.

Comment: Yes i can approve using the record using email. But the approver does not exist in salesforce I, only have is email ID through which he will reply back and approve or reject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, As of now this is not possible. You need a dummy user to assign your approvals.

The best you can do is use custom fields to store email address and then write triggers to send email when record submit for approval and write custom email service and based on the response you can approve/reject the request.